# What PHP frameworks have full localization support?

Tags: localization, php, turkish

What PHP frameworks have no problems with Turkish and especially with the Turkish characters [İ,i and I,ı](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) (like making searches with these characters and nice urls with them). Also which of them have no problems with [Bulgarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_language#Alphabet) (uses Cyrillic alphabet)? I'm asking this because all apps (Mediawiki, Firefox, Notepad++) had or still have issues with I,ı and İ,i.

Comment: What sort of issues are you seeing in MediaWiki? AFAIK there is none currently, please report. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Symfony](http://symfony.com) is supposed to be really good at localization support, you may want to check them out. I believe (though it's been a while) that the company is based out of France.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't have solid information about that to be completely honest, but zend framework should have good localization support because it is used worldwide, it is the most famous framework on earth lol :D

cakephp should "in theory" have good localization support as well because it is so well known as well

as i said, i can't confirm what i just said, but it's common sense brother

Answer (score 1):

Technically Drupal is considered a PHP framework. Though it is a framework with a UI. It completely supports localization and has some awesome addons that improve upon that even more.